# Probability change of variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with the pmf given by:

$p_X(x)=2^{-x}I_{(1,2,3...)}$. If $Y=X^2$, find the pmf of Y. If $Z=X-1$, find the pmf of Z and identify the distribution.

My Sol.

By theorem, since $Y=X^2$ is strictly increasing given domain, $f_Y(y)=2^{-(\sqrt{y})}(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt(y))}$.

By theorem again, since $Z=X-1$ is strictly increasing on the given domain, $f_Z(z)=2^{-(z+1)}$. But I cannot seem to identify what distribution it is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is some help: none of these random variables is continuous--hence you must find some DISCRETE distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the definition of the pmf, $p_X(x) = \Pr\left(X=x\right)$. Thus
$$
   p_Y(y) = \Pr\left(Y=y\right) = \Pr\left(X^2 = y \right) = \Pr\left(X = \sqrt{y} \right)
$$
Since $X(\omega)$ is a non-negative integer, the probability is only non-zero when $y$ is a complete square. Hence
$$
    p_Y(y) = 2^{-\sqrt{y}} I_{(1,4,9,16,\ldots)}
$$

Likewise $p_Z(z) = \Pr\left(Z=z\right) = \Pr\left(X=z+1\right) = 2^{-z-1} I_{(0,1,2,\ldots)}$. This known as the [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).